# How can I prove a property of the norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

How can I prove this property of the norm?
[image]
Any hint will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Use the definition of the norm of the operator.

Comment: @MarkViola  you mean I shall take the supremum of both sides of the inequality when $||x|| = 1$?

Comment: and what about this questionhttps://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523207/how-to-prove-the-following-property-of-the-norm?noredirect=1#comment5210643_2523207 ?  @MarkViola

Comment: @karimaths  so the solution is as I said above...... what about this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523207/how-to-prove-the-following-property-of-the-norm?noredirect=1#comment5210643_2523207  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The norm  $\|A\|$ by definition is $$\sup_{\|x\|_{H_1}=1}\|Ax\|$$ and sometimes $$sup_{\|x\|_{H_1}\neq0}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|_{H_1}}$$
So it is clear that when you have $\|Ax\|\leq C\|x\|_{H_1}$ then $\|A\|\leq C$.